# How to get the size (height & Width) of slides in Keynote using Applescript

Tags: annotations, applescript, keynote

I am working on an annotation product for [Keynote](http://www.apple.com/ipad/from-the-app-store/apps-by-apple/keynote.html).

What I want to do is this: when Keynote goes into slide show mode, I want to annotate (draw on) the slides. The annotations are captured into an image file, and then I want to overlay them on top of the Keynote slide with Applescript.

I have got most of this working except that when keynote goes it to slide show mode, I need to know the size (height and width) the slide that the user selected so I can scale and crop the image to the size of the slide. If I don't do this correctly, Keynote will scale the image to the size of the slide and the annotations will not be in the correct place. I already proved that this works because right now, before I annotate, I ask the user to select the slide resolution before I start the annotation, and that works great. But I want to automate this. In Keynote, there seems no way to do this using Applescript.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't entirely solve the problem but it might help you on your way. The default theme size is stored in the plist file for Keynote which you could easily access and read using Cocoa.